# C# open file with existing running process using system.diagnostics process

Tags: c#, process

I initially thought that just maybe the process would use the existing process . but . it does not . the result of the following code starts 2 sepearte sessions of the CAD software - I need to open multiple files in one existing session of the CAD software .. I tried this first:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2018\acad.exe",
         "/product \"C3D\" " + @"C:\folder\1.dwg");
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2018\acad.exe",
        "/product \"C3D\" " + @"C:\folder\2.dwg");
```

Then I did this, which works ... but I would still prefer to open a file in an existing process ... I guess the only way is to use interop ... but I would need to add an interop for each and every software app

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2018\acad.exe",
"/product \"C3D\""
+ " " + @"C:\folder\1.dwg"
+ " " + @"C:\folder\2.dwg"
+ " " + @"C:\folder\3.dwg"
);
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There's no *generic* mechanism to ask a running program to load a new file.

Comment: It is unlikely that most programs even have an interop layer.

Comment: Why aren't you using the SDK? http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-C3F3C736-40CF-44A0-9210-55F6A939B6F2

Comment: Also, "I would need to add an interop for each and every software app" - well, you need a different strategy anyway for any applications that don't *support* the concept of the program having multiple files open simultaneously. Not all applications, even those which are document-centric, are necessarily MDI applications. As a simple example of an application you almost certainly have access to in front of you - try loading two different solutions in a single Visual Studio instance.